# if statement returns false every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
function Carts() {
  let cartEval = [];
  const cartData = useSelector((state) => state.cartProducts);
  cartEval = cartData.map((item) => evalCart(item));
  function evalCart(a) {
    if (cartEval.find((b) => b.id == a.id)) {
      return { ...b, numOfTimes: numOfTimes + 1 };
    } else {
      return {
        id: a.id,
        numOfTimes: 1,
        prodTitle: a.title,
        price: a.price,
      };
    }
  }

  const totalPrice = cartData
    .map((item) => item.price)
    .reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);
  function cartRender({ item }) {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>{item.numOfTimes}</Text>
            <Text>{item.prodTitle}</Text>
            <Text>{item.price}</Text>
            <Text>Delete Button</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Total Sum of Items:{totalPrice}</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList data={cartEval} renderItem={cartRender} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default Carts;
```

This is what I want to achieve:

I need the function `evalCart(a)` to check if the `item.id` exist in the `cartEval`. If the `id` exists, increase `item.nuofItems` by 1. If it does not, create a new item with the `id` in the cartEval array.

But every time the function is called it returns false, hence the first part of the `if` statement never executes. only the `else` part. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even if the execution goes inside the `if`, it would throw an error because of `...b` - there is no `b` defined for that scope.

Comment: You are referring to `cartEval` inside `evalCart`, but `evalCart` is called during mapping the array, so `cartEval` will always be empty at that point (only after all elements were mapped, the new mapped array is returned from `map` and reassigned to the variable `cartEval`).

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT  How do you suggest I resolve this. I am pretty much new to codding, still learning.

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ  How do you suggest I resolve this. I am pretty much new to codding, still learning.

Comment: Can you show an example of the data structure and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the puzzle. This is my solution below

```
function Carts() {
  let cartEval = [];
  const cartData = useSelector((state) => state.cartProducts);
  cartData.map((item) => evalCart(item));
  function evalCart(a) {
    if (cartEval.find((b) => b.id == a.id)) {
      const dummy = cartEval.filter((d) => d.id == a.id)[0];
      cartEval.splice(cartEval.indexOf(dummy), 1, {
        ...dummy,
        numOfTimes: dummy.numOfTimes + 1,
      });
      
    } else {
      cartEval.push({
        id: a.id,
        numOfTimes: 1,
        prodTitle: a.title,
        price: a.price,
      });
    }
  }

  const totalPrice = cartData
    .map((item) => item.price)
    .reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);
  function cartRender({ item }) {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>{item.numOfTimes}</Text>
            <Text>{item.prodTitle}</Text>
            <Text>{item.price}</Text>
            <Text>Delete Button</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Total Sum of Items:{totalPrice}</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList data={cartEval} renderItem={cartRender} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default Carts;
```

Thanks for your contributions

Comment: what's the issue that you fixed ?

Comment: I need the function evalCart(a) to check if the item.id exist in the cartEval. If the id exists, increase item.nuofItems by 1. If it does not, create a new item with the id in the cartEval array.

But every time the function is called it returns false, hence the first part of the if statement never executes. only the else part.